# Does changing web hosts (changing a domain's nameservers) affect the private nameservers / glue records created under that domain?

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, centos, nameserver

We currently have a virtual dedicated server with GoDaddy and have 4 domains under it. I ended up creating private nameservers under, say mydomain_a.com, and have ns1.mydomain_a.com and ns2.mydomain_a.com as the nameservers for the other 3 domains.

Now, we're thinking of switching web hosts (not domain registrar just the host) which means I have to change mydomain_a.com's nameservers to the new host.

Will that affect or mess with the other 3 domains still pointing to ns1.mydomain_a.com and ns2.mydomain_a.com? Will that affect the private nameservers / glue records in anyway?

**Currently:**

domain: mydomain_a.com
nameservers (GoDaddy):
ns1.mydomain_a.com
ns2.mydomain_a.com

domain: mydomain_b.com
nameservers (GoDaddy):
ns1.mydomain_a.com
ns2.mydomain_a.com

**After the Change:**
domain: mydomain_a.com
nameservers (Other Host):
ns1.some_other_host_ns.com
ns2.some_other_host_ns.com

**This is my Question, Would this be affected?**
domain: mydomain_b.com
nameservers (GoDaddy):
ns1.mydomain_a.com
ns2.mydomain_a.com

Comment: Could you please provide some more information how your current config looks like? In special the glue records. I don't understand where you need glue records here and why they should be affected.

Comment: I'm not a server guy so I may not have known what I was doing. When we got the virtual dedicated server, we needed nameservers for our domains. I couldn't find GoDaddy's public nameservers and how that would point to our host so I found ways to create our own.

Comment: Clue records are usually set up for the tld only.

Comment: **Currently:**

domain: mydomain_a.com
nameservers (GoDaddy):
ns1.mydomain_a.com
ns2.mydomain_a.com

domain: mydomain_b.com
nameservers (GoDaddy):
ns1.mydomain_a.com
ns2.mydomain_a.com

**After the Change:**
domain: mydomain_a.com
nameservers (Other Host):
ns1.some_other_host_ns.com
ns2.some_other_host_ns.com

**This is my Question, Would this be affected?**
domain: mydomain_b.com
nameservers (GoDaddy):
ns1.mydomain_a.com
ns2.mydomain_a.com

Comment: Please have a look what nameservers are serving your domains: http://networking.ringofsaturn.com/Tools/dig.php If your name-servers are listed directly, you have to change this at the NIC, otherwise you have to make sure godaddy knows about the new location.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help @ThomasBerger! I appreciate it!

Comment: "Now, we're thinking of switching web hosts (not domain registrar just the host) which means I have to change mydomain_a.com's nameservers to the new host." I at least don't understand how B requires A here?

Comment: From what little I could understand with the setup, B requires A only because I added private nameservers or glue records under A. If I delete those, I'm not sure then what nameservers B should be pointed to.

Comment: "Now, we're thinking of switching web hosts (not domain registrar just the host) which means I have to change mydomain_a.com's nameservers to the new host." not necessarily, you could just change the `www` `A` or `CNAME` record to point to the new webhosting company. It would have been simpler if you gave the true names instead of obfuscating everything (and when you do that please follow RFC2606 guidelines).

Answer (score 0):

Repost my commend as answer:

Please have a look what nameservers are serving your domains: http://networking.ringofsaturn.com/Tools/dig.php

If your name-servers are listed directly, you have to change this at the NIC, otherwise you have to make sure godaddy knows about the new location.

Answer (score 0):

or simple  if you had ssh you can dig through ssh

just type command

dig domainname replace domain name with youor site name

and for nslookup use nslookup domainname

or if you dont had ssh
use

[www.nameservertools.com](http://www.nameservertools.com)

Answer (score 0):

First, please use `example.com`  when you obfuscate names and not other names.

Second, all the below depends on the TLD. I will assume we stay in gTLD land, which uses EPP as protocol between registrars and registries and its specific case of hosts as objects.

When you need to create a glue record, you need to do that through your registrar: it will create a "host" object in the registry database (which will trigger publication in registry authoritative nameservers, as needed). Things depend on the registry design but at least of in-domain nameservers (which trigger glues), the host object in the registry database is sponsored by the same registrar as the domain under which it resides.

As long as you do not change registrars, nothing happens regarding the resolution and the possible glue zones that the registry will publish.

In EPP, registrars can not transfer host objects between themselves **BUT** if domain `example.com` changes registrars, **THEN** all host objects below it will also be automatically transferred to the new registrar. This is needed for the new registrar to be able to then manage your domain correctly, but note that this transfer by itself will not trigger any change in the DNS resolution.

Note that if you are curious, you can use the whois protocol (or now the RDAP protocol) to query the registry for data about hosts objects as well as you can do for domain names.

In your example, the first domain uses glue records, but the second one not by itself (since it uses the nameservers of the first one then of course they will have glue records, but just because they are used by first domain; if they stop being used by first domain no glue records will be needed to resolve the second domain).

So if you remove them from first domain you need to make sure that their name is still properly resolved (their names must be in first domain zonefile and hence be given in responses to queries to the new authoritative nameservers of the first domain), because if they have only the glue records, without being present in the child zone (which would have been a DNS configuration error but one that could went unnoticed), then their removal from firsts domain would make them not resolvable anymore and hence would make second domain not resolvable anymore.